# how to connect to multiple collections in mongo db Realm from android

Tags: mongodb, realm

I have multiple collections in a single Realm android app. In below example, when i insert a Task object, it correctly goes into a collection called 'Task', even though i have other collections in the sam db. how is this mapping working?

https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/android/quick-start-local/#initialize-realm

Comment: We would have no idea why your code is doing whatever it's doing because you didn't include it in the question. That being said, if you're app is connected to the task Real (collection) when writing, that will be auto-generated. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you got the answer, please share it with others.